# Change shape to circle

Tags: modeling

I am doing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odhki.jpg) Blenderguru tutorial to work on my modelling skills.

[image]

**Question** At about 28:30 min in the tutorial it is demonstrated how to assign a material to a selected parts of the mesh. It should become a black **circle** and a white **circle** (green in my image). But I guess my shape is not a circle. I think the reason for that is this loop cut I made and that is not there in the tutorial.

[image]

But how to change my shape to a circle ? I have tried deleting edges but that does not work.

[image]

Comment: Please post the two questions separately.  Since you already have two answers for the first question I would recommend deleting the first part of this post and asking it separately.  It has to do with smooth shading, so as soon as you re post it I'd be happy to write an answer for it.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42112/weird-bubble-on-my-mesh here is my new question :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just select the edge loop (<kbd>Alt</kbd> +RMB). You will need to scale it flat if it isn't already, and since from your image it looks like "Y" is your local axis, scale it to zero on the y <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> axis. In my image, "Z" is the local axis, I will scale to zero on the "Z" axis.

**Before Scaling:**
[image: Before scaling]

**After scaling:**
[image]

Now use the "to sphere" tool. since it only has two dimensions, there won't be any sphere going on, just circle.

you can find this tool with <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and then searching or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I am "not completely" with you. Could you be more specific what to select and where to scale the it to zero ? I am very interested but don't understand it

Comment: editting.... please wait

Comment: I am very sorry but I still don't get it .. could you maybe visualise your instruction ?

Comment: How about now.?

Comment: no  ... I am sorry. As far as I know I have a couple of squares that i have to transform to circles. I understand from you that i have to select a square and then ?? I don't get the scaling  ... I also have understood that for To Sphere you have to subdivide your mesh ?? Anyway, I have tried with a simple cube and I don't get it sorry ... and I would like to understand !!

Comment: It's alright, i fixed it in your new questions answer.blend

Comment: Still valid in 2.9+. But "search" is found with F3.

Answer (score 1):

Close your phone.blend and start a fresh blend just to experiment with shapes and what happens when you subsurf certain geometric primitives.

When you subsurf the left figure you get the wonky circle to the right.

[image]

You need to adjust the vertices to form a nice circle prior to adding subsurf.

Use a guide Circle. (while in Edit mode you can Add meshes too, you can snap to these guide meshes and remove doubles at the end )

[image]

Comment: can I remove the sub surf, edit the mesh and add the sub surf again ?

Comment: If you haven't yet applied the subsurf you can certainly stop it from having any effect, each modifier has visibility settings. If you did apply it.. take this as a learning experience and remember to avoid applying subsurf for as long as humanly possible.

Comment: your instruction was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've taken a look at your file, i can see that all you have to do is scale the top and bottom edges around the camera. Note that my other answer is better for higher poly meshes.

[image]

Comment: ok, thanks. So like the answer of zeffii ? Just a pity that I couldn't learn how to use the To Sphere tool ;) just did not get your "scaling" remarks ... what and where to scale .... could you maybe demonstrate with a cube ?

Comment: well, as i said it doesn't work super well for lower poly. after seeing your file, you ended up not needing to scale at all! it was just to make sure everything was flush and smooth before using the sphere tool, otherwise mesh goes everywhere. ;D